# How to extract cells from structure array in order

Tags: arrays, matlab, data-structures, structure

I have a 3x3 structure array whose elements have just one field: S.

```
>> matrix

ans = 

3x3 struct array with fields:
    S
```

The content in S is a 2x2 cell whose elements are 2x2 arrays of doubles.

```
>> matrix(1)

ans = 

    S: {2x2 cell}


>> matrix(1).S

ans = 

    [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]
    [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]
```

If I didn't have the structure array (I mean, if I had a 3x3 cell array instead of the 3x3 structure array with just one field), I could access final elements using commands like:

```
cellfun(@(x)x{1,1}(1,1),matrix(:))
```

However, I can't use it because of the structure array. How could I get the same result now, with the structury array?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not convert to cell using `struct2cell`? Would that be feasible for you?

Comment: If there isn't another solution, it should be valid. But I'd prefer using a command to extract the data instead of that converting step.